# VBA - Modification of SourceData (Dynamic Range) of existing STock OHLC Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, stock, ohlc

I am working on Stock OHLC Chart present in Sheets("Exhibit") and selecting Data from Sheets("75Min"). However i am succeeding to choose appropriate data range but can not add at Line Nu 15 .SetSourcedata, could you please help me to get out from this problem
Code is as follows.

```
Sub Edit75MinChartToOHLCCandlestickChart()

Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject

Dim LastRow As Integer

Dim RngSt As Integer

    Sheets("75Min").Select

    Range("A1").Select

    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select

    LastRow = ActiveCell.Row

    RngSt = LastRow - 59

    RngEnd = LastRow + 15

    Set OHLCChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exhibit").ChartObjects(1)

        With OHLCChart.Chart 'Worksheets("Exhibit").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart

            .SetSourceData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("75Min").Range(RngSt, RngEnd)

            .ChartType = xlStockOHLC

            .HasTitle = True

            .ChartTitle.Text = "75Min Candlestick chart"

            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False

            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Price"

            .PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 242, 242)

            .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

            .Parent.Name = "OHLC Chart"

        End With

    End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Best to avoid `Select` and `Activate`.  Your range is not a valid range.  You are saying `Range(#,#)`, which isn't valid and I doubt you were trying to get whole rows.  Assuming you only wanted the first column, this will work.  You can expand the column from 1 if you need the labels.

```
Sub Edit75MinChartToOHLCCandlestickChart()

    Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("75Min")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exhibit")
    Dim MyRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RngSt As Long
    Dim RngEnd as Long
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    RngSt = LastRow - 59

    RngEnd = LastRow + 15
    
    Set MyRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 1), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 1))
    
    Set OHLCChart = ws2.ChartObjects(1)

        With OHLCChart.Chart 'Worksheets("Exhibit").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart

            .SetSourceData MyRng
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working. Can you please add code to adjust Y axis scale limited to minimum and and maximum range from begining of range to last row i.e. RngSt to Last Row? Thanks You

Comment: You should ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can include these lines to adjust the Y axis scale:

```
Dim Ymin As Double, Ymax As Double
Ymin = WorksheetFunction.Min(MyRng)
Ymax = WorksheetFunction.Max(MyRng)

With OHLCChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
  .MinimumScale = Ymin
  .MaximumScale = Ymax
End With
```

But these are probably going to be ugly axis limits. I've written a tutorial called [Calculate Nice Axis Scales in Excel VBA](https://peltiertech.com/calculate-nice-axis-scales-in-excel-vba/) which contains an algorithm to adjust the min and max outwards slightly so that the scale is more human-readable.